# How can I find the audio clips in a Facebook Messenger history

Tags: search, facebook-messenger, audio

I have a long chat history with a Facebook Messenger user.  There are a few audio clips in the history.  I don't want to scroll through 30,000 messages and clicking on audio clips.  Is there an automated or scripted solution that will allow me to easily find those links or files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## General Steps:

1. Download your entire Facebook data.
2. Navigate to the desired conversation.
3. Open the source of the conversation, and find all the strings that look like `messages/audio/SOME_LONG_NUMBER.mp4`
4. Those are your audio files from the conversation with the friend you chose.

## In Detail:

1. [**Download your entire Facebook data.**](https://www.facebook.com/help/302796099745838)

> **To download a copy of your Facebook data:**
>
> 1. Click  at the top right of any Facebook page and select **Settings**.
> 2. Click **Download a copy of your Facebook data** below your General Account Settings.
> 3. Click **Start My Archive**.

```
You'll get an email when the archive is ready for download.
```

2. **Navigate to the desired conversation.**

   - Open the archive folder you downloaded.
   - Open `index.htm` and navigate to **Messages**
   - Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search your friend's name.
   - Open the conversation.
3. **Open the source of the conversation, and find all the strings that look like `messages/audio/SOME_LONG_NUMBER.mp4`**

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, or open the selected html file with some editor.
   - Find all the names matching `*.mp4` - this will be simply achieved with some text processor and some find and replace (maybe with regex).
   - Save a list of all the file names.
   - If you want something specific and not all of them, you can search a date or phrase in the conversation page (it's a single page) and then look for your audio message.
4. **Those are your audio files from the conversation with the friend you chose.**

   - Take your list, and create a search phrase to match all the files in your list. For example, in windows explorer you can concatenate each name with an `OR` and use it to search.
   - Search the files under `archive_location/messages/audio`
   - Here are all your audio files! Start listening and find what you wanted!

Answer (score 1):

*Updated answer because the question was updated.*

**Scroll until you find it, with a script.**

Still, there isn't any nice or elegant way of doing that.

You could write a script that will scroll the conversation page until the top, and then export all the audio tags content from the page.

Another such solution, is doing pretty much the same, but on the [mobile messenger view](https://mobile.facebook.com/messages), where each time you see a block of messages and you can check the html for audio tags, and continue with the script to click on "**See Older Messages...**".

Anyway, you'd have to write a short script for doing that for you ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

---

**Scroll until you find it.**

Facebook messenger **doesn't have a good search**. It barely matches keywords, and can only show shared photos in the side panel (web view).
There isn't an option to search for shared media/files, nor any keyword I found that would match an audio clip.

[You can try downloading all you Facebook information](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=246257462227260&answer_id=453851488134522&rdrhc) and if it really gives you all your information and conversations - dig inside the messenger conversations, and hope to find it.

Comment: Your did correctly answer the question as I asked it.  However the solution is not practical. I have edited the question to reflect that I am searching for an efficient automated way to do this.

Comment: I updated the answer, but it's still not that helpful for you, because there isn't a nice solution for that ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯   You'll have to write a script to achieve that, and I wrote some guidelines for the beginning with the hope it would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I might be late to the party but there exists an extension for Chrome that saves Facebook chats including all the files in it.

It creates an archive with all the media present in a chat. You can also uncheck saving pictures and videos if you don't want them.
This way you can get the audio files you need.

Here's the link to the website: [Messages Saver for Facebook](https://chatsaver.org)

Answer (score 0):

find the audio clip using m.facebook.com and when you click on the audio clip it will automatically download it. sadly, i don't know how to find audio clips but just to keep scrolling up. but if ever you want to stop doing that in the future just download them.

Comment: Note that the OP said he has around 30K messages and he's looking for another solution rather than just scrolling